# Is there an issue with trying to pass a constant or variable to a rem() method in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there an issue with trying to pass a constant or variable to a rem() method in kotlin?

```
object TimeCalc {
    private const val SECONDS: Int = 1000
    private const val MINUTES: Int = SECONDS * 60
    private const val HOURS: Int = MINUTES * 60
    private const val DAYS: Int = HOURS * 24

    fun timeDiff(sTime: Long, eTime: Long){
        Log.i("Test", "sec $SECONDS: min $MINUTES : hrs $HOURS : days $DAYS")
        var startTime = sTime
        var endTime = eTime
        var mDiff: Int
        var mHours: Int
        var mMinutes: Int
        var mSeconds:Int
        var mMilliS: Int

        Log.i("Test", "$startTime - $endTime")

        mDiff = (endTime - startTime).toInt()
        Log.i("Test", "Diff = $mDiff")
        **mHours = mDiff.rem(DAYS)**
        Log.i("Test", "Hours = $mHours")

        Log.i("Test", "${mHours}")
    }
}
```

Result

```
I/Test: sec 1000: min 60000 : hrs 3600000 : days 86400000
I/Test: 1545062123189 - 1545062217296
I/Test: Diff = 94107
I/Test: Hours = 94107
I/Test: 94107
```

Comment: Not at all, but I find your question is not clear enough, what issues are you getting?

Comment: I am just being dumb.  I just needed to wait long enough to enable it to return a value DaHHHH!!!

Comment: Thanks Simulant for fixing the display of the result. I learned something new!